# How to use the History API or history.js to change the "active" link appropriately when the page is refreshed or when the back button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js, html5-history

My active (opened) links are highlighted with **JS** .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.nav1").click(function() {
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**links example**

```
<div id="navigation">              
    <ul>
        <li><a class="nav1" data-tab="#home" id="link-home"href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav1" data-tab="#football" id="link-football" href="#football">Football</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav1" data-tab="#hockey" id="link-hockey"href="#hockey">Hockey</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But clicking on the back button or refreshing the page doesn't remove and/or add the `.active` class to the appropriate link.

So, my question is, **how to use the History API or history.js to change the "active" link appropriately when the page is refreshed or when the back button is pressed?**

Comment: Can you give some information as to how you're managing links with History.js? For instance, are you using History.pushState?

Comment: It looks like your links navigate to '#this' and '#that'.  So on reload, those hashes are in the url still.  Perhaps you should grab the url information and use it to highlight the appropriate link.

Comment: I think that if you're going to use the history API or `history.js`, it would be better to [use clean URLs, instead of fragment identifiers ("hashs")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340121/which-one-is-better-pushstate-or-location-hash). Otherwise there is no point in using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var loc = window.location.pathname;

   $('#navigation').find('a').each(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).attr('href') == loc);
  });
</script>
```

css:

```
#navigation a.active{color: red}
```

OR

You can see this answer [Store a clicked link state using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061254/store-a-clicked-link-state-using-jquery)